# Why am I getting an uninitalized heap memory error when using a pointer (C++)?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am tasked with writing a simpler compiler in C/C++. The main() function calls the function parse_program() below in order to read in all of the input from the console and store it in a linked-list graph.

For some reason, my program breaks here:

```
while (node != NULL){
    if (node->id == ID) //Breaks here
        ...; 
    node = node->next;
}
```

With a memory access violation at 0xCDCDCDCD. Research into this shows that I have uninitialized heap memory. Doing a little experimenting, I realized that immediately after creating the node, node->next at location 0xCDCDCDCD.

```
struct Node* parse_program(){
    struct Node* node = new Node;
    cout << node;
    cout << node->next;

    ...;
    return node;
}
```

Outputs

```
0044A940 
CDCDCDCD
```

The above function is the first thing called in the program. I do have global variables.

Am I allocating memory for the node incorrectly? Could an unitialized array/pointer or something elsewhere in the program cause an error even before said array/pointer is called?

Thanks for any advice. I'm stumped on where to start looking for the problem.

Comment: you allocated node correctly - where do you expect node->next to point, you havent set it to anything so it contains junk.

Comment: What does the constructor for Node look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the options I know how to fix it:

- You may set `node->next = NULL;` manually right after the `node = new Node;`;
- You may use `new Node()` with the parens if `Node` doesn't have any user-provided constructors (e.g. `struct Node { Node *next; };`) See more details about value-initialization here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization
- You may want to add a default constructor to Node to make the initialization of `next` automatic.

Here is how to add a constructor:

```
struct Node {
  Node() : next(NULL) {}
  Node *next;
  ...
};
```

`new Node` will call your default constructor `Node()`, which will set the `next` data member to `NULL` for you.

If you omit the constructor, C++ will use the implicit `Node() {}` with `new Node`, which keeps `next` uninitialized (and its value undefined), so when you print it, you get random junk.

Comment: Actually, no. Better to leave those helper-structs aggregates. And use aggregate-initialization if wanted.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It's a matter of opinion what's better. I've added an alternative to my answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I've double-checked the last sentence of my answer and I think it's correct. I don't understand what you think is wrong with it. I think the following statement is wrong: with `struct Node { Node *next; };`, `new Node` will set `next` to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. I didn't realize that C++ "new" allocates memory but does not initialize it...

Comment: If there's no constructor at present the simplest fix is just to say `new Node()` which will value-initialize the members, whereas `new Node` will default-initialize them (which leaves pointers uninitialized)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks for the suggestion about value-initialization, I've incorporated it to my answer.

Comment: Aggregate initialization I proposed in my first comment gives the same benefits as value-initialization, and more control if you want to give initializers for some (or all) members.

Comment: @Deduplicator, agreed, but you can't use aggregate-init with `new` until C++11 and it's not clear if the OP is using C++11 or not. In this case, I think just using  `new Node()` solves the issue.